# mongodb: $eq:[key, value] expression behavior in $match different from "key:value"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.testcond.aggregate([{$match:{$eq:["color", "red"]}}])
db.testcond.aggregate([{$match:{"color":"red"}}])
```

The query using the `$eq` operator returns null result (though there are documents with `color:"red"`).

The other query without the `$eq` operator returns proper results.

Shouldn't both queries return same results?

Answer (score 0):

[$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) returns **true** if the parameters are equal and **false** otherwise. It doesn't return the matched documents as your second query.